Celery polling Redis every second
I have a Django application with two celery tasks set up. Both the tasks need to run only once at one minute after midnight (12:01 AM). This is just to update some statuses which change from "ACTIVE" to "INACTIVE" at 12:01 AM.
My goal is to reduce the number of times Celery polls Redis. Currently, it polls every second which is problematic.
I took three steps

I tried to change the settings in Django for Celery inlcuding using paramters such as CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT, CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY, CELERY_BROKER_HEARTBEAT and lastly CELERY_BEAT_MAX_LOOP_INTERVAL
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True  # Ignore task results to reduce Redis usage

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"

CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1  # Fetch only 1 task at a time
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True  # Acknowledge tasks after completion to avoid re-execution on failure

# Celery transport options
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'ssl': {
        'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_NONE  # Suggestion: CERT_REQUIRED for stronger security
    },
    'visibility_timeout': 3600,  # Timeout for long-running tasks
    'polling_interval': 30  # Poll every 30 seconds
}

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'ssl': {
        'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_NONE  # Same as broker for consistency
    }
}
# Reduce the number of threads/processes
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 1

# Disable sending task events
CELERY_WORKER_SEND_TASK_EVENTS = False

# Disable remote control commands
CELERY_WORKER_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL = False

# Disable broker heartbeat messages
CELERY_BROKER_HEARTBEAT = None

CELERY_BEAT_MAX_LOOP_INTERVAL = 3600  # Check for scheduled tasks every hour


Secondly, I even tried to set up dynamic polling so that the polling schedule is more frequent in during night time and reduced again
def set_polling_interval():
    now = datetime.now()
    if now.hour == 23 and now.minute >= 59 or now.hour == 0 and now.minute <= 15:
        # Between 11:59 PM and 12:15 AM, poll more frequently
        app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'polling_interval': 30}  # Poll every 30 seconds
        logger.info("Polling every 30 seconds between 11:59 PM and 12:15 AM.")
    else:
        # During the rest of the day, poll less frequently (every 24 hours)
        app.conf.broker_transport_options = {'polling_interval': 86400}  # Poll every 24 hours
        logger.info("Polling every 24 hours outside the midnight window.")


Lastly, because I have Django Celery Beat installed, I tried tweaking the settings there directly in the "Intervals" and "Crontabs" section, but that did not help either.


Despite these efforts, Celery is still polling Redis every second.
I checked the documentation for optimization, but struggled to find a solution there
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/optimizing.html
The following article was also referred so that maybe I can do the opposite of it but that did not work either
Can I use celery for every-second task?
